# Have any of you tried "Basic for Android"?

Tags: android, ide, frameworks, basic

I have developed for Android for half a year or so and it is going quite well. I found the learning curve steep in the beginning, but then I somehow got the idea of it all and now I don't have to fight so much anymore. Rather I spend the time on specific problems like "How to do X in Android" but that is usually simple enough to google - or to ask here :)

Anyhow, I just discovered [Basic for Android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/) and I must admit it looks attractive. It has the kind of IDE I am used to (Delphi) and it seems to be very capable. But on the other hand I am still new in the Android universe so I don't find myself competent enough to really judge the pros and cons of the tool.

Have any of you tried it, and if so, what are your thoughts about it?

Comment: It dosent matter what anyone else thinks of it. Have a go and see if it works for you. Everyone has diffrent tastes in development environment. It only takes a couple of hours playing to see if you like it.

Comment: I thought the latest version of Rad Studio XE was [promising Android support](http://delphi-insider.blogspot.com/2011/02/rad-studio-xe-in-action-php-and-android.html) OK, you have to use PHP & it's not native but it might be a better option for a Delphi user as the IDE would be exactly what you're used to.

Comment: @Tom Squires: It's not a question whether I like it or not. It's more about spending maybe weeks with it, only to discover some severe limitations I wasn't aware of, mainly because I am still new with Android. That's why I ask for other developer's experience.

Comment: @mcottle: thanks,I will take a look at that too. Actually, PHP is my main language :-)

Comment: And here I was hoping BASIC would die on newer platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a generic response since I have not used this particular toolset.  In general most of the "language translators" do not do as good of a job writing native code as a well versed programmer will.  They either translate some code or execute it under a "virtual machine" of sorts for that device. Much like Titanium Mobile (http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/).

That does not mean that they don't serve a purpose.  Some of these tools are very good for prototyping or proof of concept type work if your company (or you yourself) does not have the experience  required to do such work.

They are also very good for people who are well versed in one language and do not want or are incapable of spending the time to get over the learning curve of the native language.

In my opinion since you have already gotten over the curve you would be doing yourself a disservice by going backwards and using a tool that will generate native code that you already know how to write.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I agree with your last paragraph. Still, for prototyping I might take a look at the tool.